Transcribing Speaker Output Audio and Microphone Input Audio Real-Time using Azure AI Speech Service
Imagine you are calling a friend through your computer. You are using a microphone, your friend talks to you and you hear them through your speakers.
I want to transcribe real-time the conversation that is happening. I don't know which platform you are using for the call, so I can't use anything platform specific. For this reason, the best way to do this problem is by transcribing the microphone input and the audio that is coming out of your speakers.
Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do both at once.
I want real-time (or close to real-time, 5 seconds delay is okay) transcription of a call between someone using a laptop and a person on the other side. I am using Azure AI Speech service to transcribe from ongoing audio streams. I can use this to also transcribe from file.
For the person on our side, I can use the microphone input audio. For the person on the other side, I can use speaker output audio. Only problem is, I don't know how to combine these two things.
This code works perfectly for transcribing from microphone real-time. I just don't know how to add in the other half of the conversation from the speaker audio.
def transcribe_from_microphone():
    
I found this:

import soundcard as

This is a "sorta" answer, still not perfect.
Turns out, you can specify an input device for audio configs and use that for the transcriber: You need the "audio device endpoint ID string [...] from the IMMDevice object".
This took a while to find, but I came across this code (credit to @Damien) that finds exactly that string:


Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like I can use my headset speaker with Azure (just don't get any transcriptions), but I am able to use the Stereo Mix which after a lot of finicking does allow me to transcribe the speaker output. Additionally, the transcription is very slow and inaccurate.
I am attaching relevant code for reference:




Note: This is an altered version of my code, so it is possible that there is something that I accidentally removed that is in fact necessary, but the main idea is there. Feel free to ask questions if something doesn't work.
Didn't have to use Soundcard library or create any custom Audio Stream classes (which I found very painful). I'm gonna open up another question about the slowness, though I suspect that it is due to the threads rather than the Azure service itself.

Firstly, Try to Capture the microphone input and speaker output simultaneously. Stream both audio inputs to the Azure Speech service for transcription.
Later, Combine the transcriptions from both sources to provide a unified transcription output.

We use the soundcard library to capture audio from the microphone and speaker.


Use Azure's Speech SDK to create two separate recognizers: one for the microphone input and one for the speaker output.
App.py:
import threading
import soundcard as sc
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import queue
import warnings

# Suppress the SoundcardRuntimeWarning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=sc.SoundcardRuntimeWarning)

# Your Azure subscription key and region
audio_key = 'YOUR_AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY'
audio_region = 'YOUR_AZURE_REGION'

# Queue for passing audio data between threads
mic_queue = queue.Queue()
speaker_queue = queue.Queue()

# Function to capture microphone audio
def capture_mic_audio(mic_queue):
    mic = sc.get_microphone(id=str(sc.default_microphone().name))
    with mic.recorder(samplerate=48000) as mic_recorder:
        while True:
            data = mic_recorder.record(numframes=1024)
            mic_queue.put(data)

# Function to capture speaker audio
def capture_speaker_audio(speaker_queue):
    speaker = sc.get_microphone(id=str(sc.default_speaker().name), include_loopback=True)
    with speaker.recorder(samplerate=48000) as speaker_recorder:
        while True:
            data = speaker_recorder.record(numframes=1024)
            speaker_queue.put(data)

# Function to create an audio input stream for Azure Speech SDK
def create_audio_input_stream(audio_queue):
    class AudioInputStream(speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStreamCallback):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
        
        def read(self, buffer, size):
            try:
                data = audio_queue.get(block=False)
                buffer[:len(data)] = data
                return len(data)
            except queue.Empty:
                return 0

        def close(self):
            pass

    return speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStream(AudioInputStream()))

# Function to start Azure speech recognition
def start_recognition(audio_config, speech_config, name):
    recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
    
    def recognized(evt):
        if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            print(f"{name} recognized: {evt.result.text}")
        elif evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            print(f"{name} recognized: No speech could be recognized")
        elif evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
            cancellation_details = evt.result.cancellation_details
            print(f"{name} recognized: Canceled: {cancellation_details.reason}")
            if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
                print(f"Error details: {cancellation_details.error_details}")
    
    recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized)
    recognizer.start_continuous_recognition_async()
    return recognizer

# Main function
def main():
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=audio_key, region=audio_region)
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language = "en-US"

    # Start capturing audio
    threading.Thread(target=capture_mic_audio, args=(mic_queue,), daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=capture_speaker_audio, args=(speaker_queue,), daemon=True).start()

    # Create audio input streams
    mic_audio_input = create_audio_input_stream(mic_queue)
    speaker_audio_input = create_audio_input_stream(speaker_queue)

    # Start speech recognizers
    mic_recognizer = start_recognition(mic_audio_input, speech_config, "Microphone")
    speaker_recognizer = start_recognition(speaker_audio_input, speech_config, "Speaker")

    # Keep the program running to process transcriptions
    try:
        while True:
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        mic_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition_async()
        speaker_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition_async()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


As you can see in the above, I have used two separate threads to capture audio from the microphone and speaker. Each thread captures audio continuously and puts it into a queue.

Also create a custom PullAudioInputStreamCallback to feed audio data from the queue to the Azure Speech SDK.


Result:

Modified:
Converting NumPy array to bytes.
def read(self, buffer: memoryview) -> int:
    try:
        data = audio_queue.get(block=False)
        buffer[:len(data)] = data.tobytes()  # Convert to bytes
        return len(data)
    except queue.Empty:
        return 0


Hi Suresh.
Thank you very much for your response. I was looking into the PullAudioInputStreamCallback class too, and it seems like this is the correct answer.
Unfortunately, I am running into quite a few errors:
First, the sc.get_microphone() required an id, so I added in str(sc.default_microphone().name) to fix that.
The terminal is also getting spammed with:
SoundcardRuntimeWarning: data discontinuity in recording   warnings.warn("data discontinuity in recording", SoundcardRuntimeWarning)
Do you know how to silence/suppress these warnings? Also, I don't see any transcrip

tion in the terminal as you did in your screenshot.

Yes, sc.get_microphone() needs an ID. Using str(sc.default_microphone().name) is a better approach to specify the default microphone. To suppress the SoundcardRuntimeWarning, you can use the warnings module in Python. Please check my updated code this module will allow you to ignore the specific warnings about data discontinuity. I have commented for each of the change in my above code for more clarification.

Removed size from def read(self, buff): because unnecessary and not in parent function.
Replaced SpeechRecognizer and related things with ConversationTranscriber and related things to better fit use case.
Not running into any errors, but def transcribed(evt) and def transcribing(evt) are not being called even though I have connected the listeners.
print(data) in the capture_mic_audio function shows that there is audio being collected.
Code: https://pastebin.com/yN5tD7tn
Thanks Suresh for all your help.

Experimenting more..
Adding print() statements to read() function for debugging:
def read(self, buffer: memoryview) -> int:
      try:
          data = audio_queue.get(block=False)
          buffer[:len(data)] = data
          print(buffer)
          return len(data)
      except queue.Empty:
          print(0)
          return 0

Running the code simply prints 0 once.
Removing block=False results in the following error:
ValueError: memoryview assignment: lvalue and rvalue have different structures

in line 49: buffer[:len(data)] = data

Still trying this out...
data is a numpy array, and buffer takes in Bytes. I am using the numpy library to convert the audio data collected to Bytes with tobytes().
Other issue is that len(buffer) < len(data), 8192 < 3200.
I can use a chunking procedure to just make it fit, and it does sort of work! My print() call in transcribed() is printing empty messages, but the print() call in transcribing() is not printing, so the transcriber isn't actually picking up words. I'm guessing that the chunking is cutting up the audio bytes and making it unusable. Pasting code...

@adityapgupta211 Error occurs because the buffer is a memoryview object, and you’re trying to assign a NumPy array (data) to it. convert the NumPy array to bytes before assigning it to the memoryview I have added the code snippet in my above answer have a look and also try to split the data into smaller chunks that fit the buffer size. However, be cautious about splitting at arbitrary points, as it may affect the transcription quality. Consider using overlapping chunks to avoid losing context.

Hi Suresh, thanks for the reply. I already tried converting the numpy array into bytes which I described in my earlier comment. I tried to use overlapping chunks, but still no results. It doesn't seem like I'm getting complete answer to this question, so I am moving on to try an alternate solution: I will be trying to set up phone calling with Azure Communication service and transcribe that maybe. Thank you Suresh for pointing me in the direction of the custom class. If you do have anything else to add for this solution, I would still be ready to switch over and work here again.

If you avoid using soundcard library and focus on a simpler approach, Use the pnputil command to list audio endpoints and select the appropriate microphone and speaker devices. Then set up separate transcribers for the microphone and speaker using Azure Speech SDK's built-in audio device selection this will Print or log the transcription results for both microphone and speaker inputs.

Hi Suresh, I tried this method, and I am able to find all my connected audio devices. However, the transcriber is unable to pick up anything from my speakers. My workaround was using the stereo mix speaker as it functions as a microphone, but I would rather not use the stereo mix because it is windows dependent. I am assuming that Azure does not accept sound sinks as sound-devices to transcribe from.
